# Changing the branch name from main to a different branch still deploys from main branch on Vercel

Tags: deployment, vercel

I have tried to change the production branch for a project on vercel from main to another branch, but when I redeploy, the source remains main.
What am I doing wrong?

[[the source is still the main branch after changing and saving the signuplast branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmXZR.png)][[i changed the branch name to signuplast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8KRX.png)]

I was expecting to deploy the branch I am working on but Vercel only deploys the main branch in my project.

Answer (score 0):

did you try on cli? when you work on your second branch in vs-code install vercel as global.

```
npm install -g vercel
vercel --version
vercel login
```

and then when you want to see development version of your project run this command

```
vercel dev
```

after checking

```
vercel --prod
```

of course you must be on second branch. by this way always you must see your second branch on vercel. i worked on cli and i had no problem. in my opinion easy way.